# How do I validate Japanese numbers using regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

Below I attach my script in Perl. I am testing the number 1234 with one equivalent in Japanese. (I copied from Wikipedia... maybe it is not 100% correct).

Using

```
\p{decimal number}+
\p{Number}+
\d+
```

The code works fine for the ASCII version, but for Japanese I find only this example:

```
[0-9\x{3041}-\x{3096}\x{30a1}-\x{30fc}\x{4e00}-\x{9faf}]
```

What I am doing wrong in this case?

```
use 5.016;

use utf8;
use charnames   qw< :full >;
use feature     qw< unicode_strings >;

use Test::More tests => 2;

sub is_valid {
  my $string = shift;

  $string ~~ /^[0-9\x{3041}-\x{3096}\x{30a1}-\x{30fc}\x{4e00}-\x{9faf}]+$/u

  #/\p{decimal number}+/msx
}

ok(is_valid("1234"), "ascii");
ok(is_valid("壱弐参四"), "japanese");
```

Comment: The CJK idiographs from `U+4F00` to `U+9FCC` are all classified as `Letter, Other` (Lo) in unicode, so they don't match `Number` or `Number, Decimal` categories.

Comment: humm... I'm using the wrong japanese string... :/

Comment: Thiago, i don't know about the perl problem but i know  little of japanese. 1,2,3,4 are respectively 一、二，三、四

Comment: @DavideBerra: There is another set for formal writing (bank note).

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj: I haven't seen `壱弐参四`, or even the `一二三四` being used, except for year in the second case. Usually, it is `千二百三十四`. The `壱弐参四` (called daiji) are used in things involving money. Other than that, it is not common to see them in normal text.

Comment: What is your question? For starters, what are you trying to do? You ask what you are doing wrong, which is impossible to answer if you don't tell us what you are trying to do. Are you trying to validate numbers? If so, you have the weirdest definition of number I've ever heard. ("Taxi" in Japanese is number, and "-4" isn't!)

Comment: I was trying to identify numbers, in ascii or japanese (to be more specific: find a code like \d{4}\s?[A-Z]{2}). I try the \d and it is not work. I don't know japanese but correct me if I'm wrong: the \d can match javanese, arabic, thay and many other types of numbers but not japanese, right?

Comment: `\d` matches digits, including the Japanese ones (U+FF10..FF19). But you want to match a "number". That's a whole other ballpark. How do you define "number"? I consider "-4", "1.4" and "one" to be numbers, generally speaking.

Comment: １２３４ ? humm.. I never think about this. Thanks!

Comment: how I define a "number"? good question. But i was thinking in a hypotesis of someone, in japan for example, add a different but valid groups of characters in some input field (like japanese numbers).

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj: For input, you can restrict user to digits in ASCII, and full-width digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code passes for me on v5.14.

The `/u` doesn't do what you think it does there since you have just ASCII in the pattern. You require v5.16, and that showed up in v5.14. No big whoop unless there's some v5.16 enhancement you're trying to use.

As many people have noted, there's a semantic difference between numbers and digits. I think you just want to match a run of digits. The problem is that the UCS doesn't label the characters you want to match as digits.

As such, you created a very expansive character class to do that. I think you're stuck with that. You probably don't want to keep doing that. You could hide it all in a subroutine, but you can also define additional properties. You create a specially named subroutine that returns a string with lines of character ranges as hex values. Here's an example for [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html):

```
sub InKana {
    return <<END;
3040\t309F
30A0\t30FF
END
}
```

You might use the [Unicode::Unihan](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aUnihan) module to figure out which points you want. You can do it with code, but all this is doing in looking in the [Unihan database](http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihangridindex.html) file that's the same name as the method. Someone who actually knows Japanese will have to tweak this to select the right characters:

```
use v5.10;

use Number::Range;
use Unicode::Unihan;

my $db = Unicode::Unihan->new;
my $range = Number::Range->new;

foreach my $u ( 0 .. 0x01dfff ) {
    my $char = chr $u;
    next unless $char =~ /\p{Script: Han}/;
    my $value = 
        $db->PrimaryNumeric( $char ) ||
        $db->AccountingNumeric( $char ) ||
        $db->OtherNumeric( $char )
        ;
    next unless defined $value;
    my $hex = sprintf "%X", $u;
    say chr($u), " (U+$hex) has numeric value: ", $value;
    $range->addrange( $u );
    }

my $sub = 
q(sub InJapaneseDigit {
    return <<'HERE';
)

.

join( "\n", 
    map { 
        join "\t", 
            map { sprintf "%X", $_ } 
            split /\.\./;  
        } 
    split /,/, $range->range 
    )

.

qq(\nHERE\n});

say $sub;
```

That program outputs:

```
㐅 (U+3405) has numeric value: 5
㒃 (U+3483) has numeric value: 2
㠪 (U+382A) has numeric value: 5
㭍 (U+3B4D) has numeric value: 7
一 (U+4E00) has numeric value: 1
七 (U+4E03) has numeric value: 7
万 (U+4E07) has numeric value: 10000
三 (U+4E09) has numeric value: 3
九 (U+4E5D) has numeric value: 9
二 (U+4E8C) has numeric value: 2
五 (U+4E94) has numeric value: 5
亖 (U+4E96) has numeric value: 4
亿 (U+4EBF) has numeric value: 100000000
什 (U+4EC0) has numeric value: 10
仟 (U+4EDF) has numeric value: 1000
仨 (U+4EE8) has numeric value: 3
伍 (U+4F0D) has numeric value: 5
佰 (U+4F70) has numeric value: 100
億 (U+5104) has numeric value: 100000000
兆 (U+5146) has numeric value: 1000000000000
兩 (U+5169) has numeric value: 2
八 (U+516B) has numeric value: 8
六 (U+516D) has numeric value: 6
十 (U+5341) has numeric value: 10
千 (U+5343) has numeric value: 1000
卄 (U+5344) has numeric value: 20
卅 (U+5345) has numeric value: 30
卌 (U+534C) has numeric value: 40
叁 (U+53C1) has numeric value: 3
参 (U+53C2) has numeric value: 3
參 (U+53C3) has numeric value: 3
叄 (U+53C4) has numeric value: 3
四 (U+56DB) has numeric value: 4
壱 (U+58F1) has numeric value: 1
壹 (U+58F9) has numeric value: 1
幺 (U+5E7A) has numeric value: 1
廾 (U+5EFE) has numeric value: 9
廿 (U+5EFF) has numeric value: 20
弌 (U+5F0C) has numeric value: 1
弍 (U+5F0D) has numeric value: 2
弎 (U+5F0E) has numeric value: 3
弐 (U+5F10) has numeric value: 2
拾 (U+62FE) has numeric value: 10
捌 (U+634C) has numeric value: 8
柒 (U+67D2) has numeric value: 7
漆 (U+6F06) has numeric value: 7
玖 (U+7396) has numeric value: 9
百 (U+767E) has numeric value: 100
肆 (U+8086) has numeric value: 4
萬 (U+842C) has numeric value: 10000
貮 (U+8CAE) has numeric value: 2
貳 (U+8CB3) has numeric value: 2
贰 (U+8D30) has numeric value: 2
阡 (U+9621) has numeric value: 1000
陆 (U+9646) has numeric value: 6
陌 (U+964C) has numeric value: 100
陸 (U+9678) has numeric value: 6

sub InJapaneseDigit {
        return <<'HERE';
3405
3483
382A
3B4D
4E00
4E03
4E07
4E09
4E5D
4E8C
4E94
4E96
4EBF    4EC0
4EDF
4EE8
4F0D
4F70
5104
5146
5169
516B
516D
5341
5343    5345
534C
53C1    53C4
56DB
58F1
58F9
5E7A
5EFE    5EFF
5F0C    5F0E
5F10
62FE
634C
67D2
6F06
7396
767E
8086
842C
8CAE
8CB3
8D30
9621
9646
964C
9678
HERE
}
```